# Lag in Game Loop as the game progresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, game-loop

Here is my small attempt at working with Game Loop. [Here is the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8U8F2/). (keep clicking in gray area to start it).

The issue is that the game animations get choppy after clicking for a while, and reach to a point where it's like a stop motion thing, and after that I need to kill the browser tab.

Surely there is something I'm missing here. May be something like a delay that needs to be inserted when the game is idle. 

Here is the code that i've been working on:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="player"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var player = {
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    image: "",
    score: 0,
    highestScore: 0
};
var newColor=null;

/*Game loop starts here*/
var gameLoop = function () {
    $(".container").on("click", function () {
        $(".player").stop().animate({
            bottom: "+=100px"
        }, 300, function () {
            $(".player").animate({
                bottom: "0"
            }, 800);
        });
    });
/* some more calls to updating player properties etc etc will come here*/
};
/*Game loop ends here*/

/*Run the Game Loop*/
setInterval(gameLoop, 16);
```

---

To state my question:
How do I prevent the lag that I'm experiencing as the game progresses?

Comment: It is hard to say where the lag is coming from and if it is due to just the loop.  That said I do notice you keep doing $('.player') selector twice per loop.  It seems you could gain some efficiency by selecting player only 1 time.

Comment: Hello, I think you'll achieve what you want to do more easily with this link: http://apps.apolinariopassos.com.br/flappygenerator/en/

Comment: @XavierDelamotte What I'm doing isn't a Flappy bird clone. Its supposed to be some guy with jet pack. Also my attempt to learn building Games using this Game Loop.

Answer (score 4):

The lag is coming from you assigning a new click handler every 16 ms.

Extract the following code outside of the gameLoop function:

```
$(".container").on("click", function () {
    $(".player").stop().animate({
        bottom: "+=100px"
    }, 300, function () {
        $(".player").animate({
            bottom: "0"
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

You haven't posted the rest of your code, but make sure that in the gameLoop you update the state of the game only and don't re-create the mechanisms that keep the game running.